# Duplicate dataframe depending on elements on a collection

Tags: python, pandas

I need to "duplicate" the elements of a `DataFrame` as many times as elements in a collection (let's say a list to simplify it). It might be hard to explain by words, so I will show my code:

```
In [1]: data = {char: [] for char in 'abcd'}
In [2]: n = 3
In [3]: properties = [i for i in range(1, n + 1)]
In [4]: l = list(range(1, 11))
In [5]: for e in l:
    ...:     data['a'].append(e + e)
    ...:     data['b'].append(e * e)
    ...:     data['c'].append(e ** e)
    ...:     data['d'].append(1.0 / e)
    ...:
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
    a    b            c         d
0   2    1            1  1.000000
1   4    4            4  0.500000
2   6    9           27  0.333333
3   8   16          256  0.250000
4  10   25         3125  0.200000
5  12   36        46656  0.166667
6  14   49       823543  0.142857
7  16   64     16777216  0.125000
8  18   81    387420489  0.111111
9  20  100  10000000000  0.100000
```

based on properties, I need to produce the following `DataFrame`:

```
     a    b            c         d  property
0    2    1            1  1.000000         1
1    4    4            4  0.500000         1
2    6    9           27  0.333333         1
3    8   16          256  0.250000         1
4   10   25         3125  0.200000         1
5   12   36        46656  0.166667         1
6   14   49       823543  0.142857         1
7   16   64     16777216  0.125000         1
8   18   81    387420489  0.111111         1
9   20  100  10000000000  0.100000         1
10   2    1            1  1.000000         2
11   4    4            4  0.500000         2
12   6    9           27  0.333333         2
13   8   16          256  0.250000         2
14  10   25         3125  0.200000         2
15  12   36        46656  0.166667         2
16  14   49       823543  0.142857         2
17  16   64     16777216  0.125000         2
18  18   81    387420489  0.111111         2
19  20  100  10000000000  0.100000         2
20   2    1            1  1.000000         3
21   4    4            4  0.500000         3
22   6    9           27  0.333333         3
23   8   16          256  0.250000         3
24  10   25         3125  0.200000         3
25  12   36        46656  0.166667         3
26  14   49       823543  0.142857         3
27  16   64     16777216  0.125000         3
28  18   81    387420489  0.111111         3
29  20  100  10000000000  0.100000         3
```

which is to repeat my data array depending on the amount of elements in properties, and adding the column property. Currently I am using two loops nested loops to achieve it as follows:

```
new_data = {'a': [], 'b': [], c: [], d: [], 'property': []}
properties = [1, 2, 3]
for property_id in properties:
    for e in l:
        new_data['property'].append(property_id)
        new_data['a'].append(e + e)
        new_data['b'].append(e * e)
        new_data['c'].append(e ** e)
        new_data['d'].append(1.0 / e)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
```

However, I hope there is a way to simplify this logic just using the original `data` dictionary I have or the `df` and duplicating the frame as many properties I have.

The main goal of this problem is to improve the performance of this logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `concat`

Are you looking to `concat` `df` with itself?

```
df = pd.concat(
       [df] * len(properties), ignore_index=True
).assign(property=np.repeat(properties, len(df)))
```

---

#### `reindex` + `tile`

```
df = df.reindex(np.tile(df.index, len(properties))).assign(
    property=np.repeat(properties, len(df))
)
```

Comment: I am stunned at your answer. You make it look so simple. Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. I knew about `concat`, but I didn't know about `assign`

Comment: would you mind explaining about `assign` in the answer?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf No problem. `assign` is an easy way to create a new column. It's the same as `df  = pd.concat(...); df['property'] = ...`. I take the `property` list and repeat it as many times as needed based on the length of `df`.

Comment: I tested `concat` against `reindex` + `np.tile`, it seems the later is faster.

Comment: @liliscent You mean `df.reindex(np.tile(df.index, len(properties)))`?

Comment: @coldspeed Yes.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf We've found another solution for you... test and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: @liliscent I tested it on larger data: `df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True); properties = list(range(50))` and concat still seems faster...

Comment: @liliscent, thanks for mentioning that solution too.

Comment: I have tried both solutions using `%%time`, and it seems that `concat` is a bit faster in general than `reindex` + `tile`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a list of dataframes and then concat them with adding a new column everytime.

```
dfs = [df.assign(property=k)  for k in properties]
data = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Spare yourself the `reset_index` by using `ignore_index=True` in `pd.concat`.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf, sure.